# Is there a reason why I shouldn't push HEAD instead of a specific branch

Tags: git

Sometimes I am lazy and can't be bothered to check what branch I am currently working on.

Is there a reason why I ***shouldn't***

```
git push origin HEAD
```

?

Comment: No...what makes you think that you shouldn't do this? It's just a short hand for pushing the head of the current branch.

Comment: I go even shorter and just type `git push`